# Python write/read rgb Image

Tags: python, image, rgb

I have tested to write and read an one pixel jpg file using Image:

```
data_ori = np.zeros((1, 1, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
data_ori[0,0]=(1,20,300)
img = Image.fromarray(data_ori, 'RGB')
img.save("toto2.jpg")
im = Image.open("toto2.jpg")
pix = im.load()
```

**print(pix[0,0])** gives **(2, 20, 44)**. Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Could this be an overflow error? 300 does not fit in uint8, `300-256 = 44 with 1 overflow` so 1 is added to the R channel? What happens when you use smaller number (less than 256)

Comment: jpeg is a lossy format, so you can't be sure you'll get the exact same numbers back.

Comment: data_ori[0,0]=(1,20,40) return (2, 20, 42) ...

Answer (score 0):

@Aran-Fey using gif format works well